# NoSuchFieldError -> BasicHeadValueFormatter.INSTANCE Android Studio

Tags: android, apache, android-studio

I get the following error for some reason. I saw that there are multiple posts about this but I couldn't find a solution. I have the http files in libs folder in android. I know that the first line in dependencies compiles them,but I also added them manually in the project structure because I thought it would solve the problem. No luck so far.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: org.apache.http.message.BasicHeaderValueFormatter.INSTANCE
```

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.4.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.4.1.jar')
}
```

This line causes it: `totalSize = entity.getContentLength();`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having the same problem:

I solved the problem by downloading older files.

This is what I have in my dependencies now:

```
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
```